# stream API collect method compiler error - Object cannot be cast to List

Tags: java, java-stream

I cannot see what the problem is with my stream api logic.
It tells me the following

> [ERROR] mystuff/MandantContentFetcher.java:[67,23] incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List

this is my stream method:

```
static List<MandantLinkCheckerEntry> createMandantLinkCheckerEntries(Struct struct) {
    Map<String, Object> linkCheckerMandants = struct.toNestedMaps();
    return linkCheckerMandants.values().parallelStream()
            .map(Map.class::cast)
            .map(MandantLinkCheckerEntry::convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

which uses this method reference:

```
  private static MandantLinkCheckerEntry convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry(Map<String, Object> entryToConvert) {
    return new MandantLinkCheckerEntry(String.valueOf(entryToConvert.get("mandant.path")),
            String.valueOf(entryToConvert.get("mail.to")),
            Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(entryToConvert.get("active"))));
  }
```

Why does he see a **Object**? The method reference in the 2nd **map** does return a **MandantLinkCheckerEntry**. Also I assume **collect** does create a List with the streamed values as generic type but it seems that he converts the type of the stream (which is Object here as the Stream initiator is `Map<String, Object`). How can I help him cast this to a List?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Its a maven compilation error I have no explicit stacktrace. Is it regainable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, class literals can’t refer to generic types, so `Map.class` evaluates to a `Class<Map>`, associated with the raw type `Map`, and that’s what you get when calling `cast` on it.

So the subsequent `.map(MandantLinkCheckerEntry::convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry)` bears an unchecked operation assigning the `Map` to `Map<String, Object>` which causes the compiler to continue without Generics at all for this expression, ending up with a call of `.collect(Collectors.toList());` on the raw type `Stream` whose erased return is `Object`.

When you use

```
static List<MandantLinkCheckerEntry> createMandantLinkCheckerEntries(Struct struct) {
    Map<String, Object> linkCheckerMandants = struct.toNestedMaps();
    return linkCheckerMandants.values().parallelStream()
            .map(Map.class::cast)
            .map((Function<Map,MandantLinkCheckerEntry>)MandantLinkCheckerEntry::convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

instead, the unchecked operation happens when binding the method `convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry` to `Function<Map, MandantLinkCheckerEntry>`, but not with the surrounding `map` method invocation, so the stream chain can be compiled without errors.

You will always unavoidably have an unchecked operation somewhere, as the correctness of a conversion from `Object` to `Map<String, Object>` can’t be checked at runtime. The cleanest solution would be having `struct.toNestedMaps()` return a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` in the first place:

```
static List<MandantLinkCheckerEntry> createMandantLinkCheckerEntries(Struct struct) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> linkCheckerMandants = struct.toNestedMaps();
    return linkCheckerMandants.values().parallelStream()
            .map(MandantLinkCheckerEntry::convertMapToMandantCheckerEntry)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: sadly this `Map<String, Map<String, Object>> linkCheckerMandants = (Map<String, Map<String, Object>>)struct.toNestedMaps();` is not possible. It is what I tried at first. **inconvertible types** is the error here

Comment: Well, I meant that `struct.toNestedMaps()` should return that type in the first place, so that a cast is not necessary. Otherwise, you *can* do `Map<String, Map<String, Object>> linkCheckerMandants = (Map)struct.toNestedMaps();`, but that’s again an unchecked operation.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
.map(Map.class::cast)
```

To this one:

```
.map(o -> (Map<String, Object>) o)
```

Of course, this cast is totally unsafe and will generate a warning, but at least, you will preserve generic type parameters along the stream pipeline.